# C++ - How to cout the person with the highest score in a program

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that allows the user to input some names and integers for a soccer game, ie input the player's name, jersey number, & points scored, and then prints it all at the end.

How would I go about finding the player's name who scored the most points, and print that?

This is my incomplete code below:

```cpp
void showHighest(Player p[], int size)
{
    int high = 0;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        if (high < p[counter].points)
        {
            high = p[counter].points;
        }

        if (p[counter].points   )
        {

        }
    }
    cout << "The player with the most points was: " << p[high].name << "with " << high << "amount of points." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track the **index** of the highest player in the array, not just the highest **points**.  In your `cout` statement, you are using the highest **points** as if it were an **index**, which it is not.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void showHighest(Player p[], int size)
{
    int highest_points = 0;
    int highest_index = -1;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < size; ++counter)
    {
        if (highest_points < p[counter].points)
        {
            highest_index = counter;
            highest_points = p[counter].points;
        }
    }

    if (highest_index != -1)
        cout << "The player with the most points was: " << p[highest_index].name << " with " << highest_points << " amount of points." << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you can initialize the tracking variables to the info of the 1st player, and start the loop at the 2nd player, eg:

```cpp
void showHighest(Player p[], int size)
{
    if (size < 1) return;

    int highest_points = p[0].points;
    int highest_index = 0;

    for (int counter = 1; counter < size; ++counter)
    {
        if (highest_points < p[counter].points)
        {
            highest_index = counter;
            highest_points = p[counter].points;
        }
    }

    cout << "The player with the most points was: " << p[highest_index].name << " with " << highest_points << " amount of points." << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, use a *pointer* to track the `Player` with the highest `points`, eg:

```cpp
void showHighest(Player p[], int size)
{
    if (size < 1) return;

    Player* highest_player = &p[0];

    for (int counter = 1; counter < size; ++counter)
    {
        if (highest_player->points < p[counter].points)
        {
            highest_player = &p[counter];
        }
    }

    cout << "The player with the most points was: " << highest_player->name << " with " << highest_player->points << " amount of points." << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the standard [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm to find the `Player` with the highest `points` without using a manual loop, eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

void showHighest(Player p[], int size)
{
    if (size < 1) return;

    auto p_end = p + size;
    auto it = std::max_element(p, p_end,
        [](const Player &a, const Player &b){
            return a.points < b.points;
        }
    );

    cout << "The player with the most points was: " << it->name << " with " << it->points << " amount of points." << endl;
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with something very similar, here is my code for it.

`void showHighest(Player p[], int size)
{
    static int high = 0;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        if (p[counter].points > p[high].points)
        {
            high = counter;
        }
    }

    cout << "The player with the most points was: " << p[high].name << endl; 
}`

Comment: @Tazader There is no good reason to use a `static` variable in this situation. `high` should be a *non-static* local variable. Also, if you are going to initialize `high` to the index of the 1st player, then your loop should start with the 2nd player, so initialize `counter` to 1 instead of 0 (like shown in my 2nd example). Also, your code is *assuming* that `size > 0` is always true, so make sure the caller is validating that before it calls `showHighest()`, otherwise `showHighest()` should account for the possibility of being passed in an empty array (all of my examples do that).

Answer (score -2):

A good solution will be to set the change the 'high' integer into a player object.
Then instead of holding only the highest score you will hold the player object.

```
void showHighest(Player p[], int size)
{
    Player* high;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
    {
        if (high.points < p[counter].points)
        {
            high = p[counter];
        }

    }
    cout << "The player with the most points was: " << high.name << "with " << high.points << "amount of points." << endl;
}
```

Obviously there are many other ways as suggested above.
Another way which is less effective is to "remember" the highest score value (as you do) and then check which player has this amount of points:

```
    void showHighest(Player p[], int size)
    {
        int high = 0;
    
        for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
        {
            if (high < p[counter].points)
            {
                high = p[counter].points;
            }
        }
        string name = "";
        for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++ )
        {
          if(player[counter].points == high)
          {
             name = p[counter].name;
          }
        }
        cout << "The player with the most points was: " << name << "with" << high << "amount of points." << endl;
    }
```

you can find many other ways.
I would recomend the first one due the use of the OOP advanteges you have at C++.

Comment: You right. I fixed it. long time of jave and python has made me forget some.
But still the main idea is clear and same.

Comment: Your 1st example is a memory leak, since you are `new`'ing a `Player` object that you don't `delete` when done using it. A search function shouldn't be allocating any memory at all, so get rid of the `new` altogether, eg: `void showHighest(Player p[], int size) { Player* high = nullptr; for (int counter = 0; counter < size; ++counter) { if (!high || high->points < p[counter].points) { high = &p[counter]; } } if (high) cout << "The player with the most points was: " << high->name << " with " << high->points << " amount of points." << endl; }`

Comment: Your 2nd example is just wasteful of the CPU, there is no good reason to run 2 repetitive loops with 1 loop will suffice. When you store the `high` points, you may as well store the corresponding `name` at the same time.